# Eclipse/Java while debugging with no source why some ask 'attach a source' while some say 'edit source look up path'

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have a java application which depends library that I do not have source code for. I set a break point at a method entry point, and when it hits I am greeted with a "Souce not found" screen with some details, and a button that says 'Attach Source...', but I go down the stack trace a bit and notice that for some other classes, the screen shows nothing but a red 'Source not found' and a button 'Edit Source Lookup Path'. What are the differences?

I ask because, if I click into the first stack, I can do evaluation and everything in 'Expression' window whereas in the second I cannot. There must be something I don't understand. Please any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add screen-shots for better understanding.If not able to attach, you can share screen shots via http://postimage.org/

Comment: You mention you don't have the source for library, which I'm assuming contains `ScriptHandler`.  Do you have the source for `ChartReportItemPresentationImpl`?  Is that where your breakpoint is?

Comment: @davidfmatheson I don't have source for `ChartReportItemPresentationImpl` either. My breakpoint is on the `ScriptHandler` class, which comes compiled in a .jar as a dependency. The `Impl` class I got from the stacktrace. What I did notice is that although I don't have source for both classes, `ScriptHandler` is included in my build path as one of the .class files, whereas `PresentationImpl` is not. What confuses me is how come a class that is referenced is not on my buildpath. This could be a naive question, so apology beforehand.